# WooCommerce email templete customization for custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email-templates

I have integrate WooCommerce in wordpress. After placed order and checkout i am getting one default email in recipient mail box. This is working fine.

Now i need to customize them. Suppose i have 2 products and each have quantity 2-items. So, customize email template as per quantity.

For e.g

```
product name : Mouse
quantity : 2

product name : Keyboard
quantity : 3
```

So here total item quantity are 5. I need to generate 5 different random password and add in email template. Which is later send to recipient after success of payment.

Comment: Are you wanting help to change the layout or the to generate 5 random passwords?

Comment: @howlin Yes exactly. I want to change email template and would like to add 5 random password. It may depend on no of quantity. If quantity are 10 then generate 10 random password.